# AttributeError: module ... has no attribute 'CustomRegisterSerializer'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am trying to use a custom register serializer with `django-rest-auth`.

The name of the users app is `myapp.users` and the serializer file is in that app.

In the serializers file I have:

```
class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
```

and in `settings.py`:

```
REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {  
    "REGISTER_SERIALIZER": 'myapp.users.serializers.CustomRegisterSerializer'
}
```

But this error keeps coming:

```
AttributeError: module 'myapp.users.serializers.CustomRegisterSerializer' has no attribute 'CustomRegisterSerializer'
```

Edit 1:

installed apps in settings

```
THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    'crispy_forms',  # Form layouts
    'allauth',  # registration
    'allauth.account',  # registration
    'allauth.socialaccount',  # registration
    'rest_framework', #api
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'corsheaders',
     'rest_framework_tracking',
]
LOCAL_APPS = [
    # custom users app
    'myapp.users.apps.UsersConfig',

]
INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS
```

Edit 2:
    from django.apps import AppConfig

```
class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp.users'
    verbose_name = "Users"
```

What do you think  I'm missing?

Comment: Please show your INSTALLED_APPS settings as well.

Comment: Can you post your myapp.users.app.UserConfig. It is weird that its thinking that serializer is a module and not a class.

Comment: I have updated it